# UDP Tunnel via SSH Confusion

Tags: ssh-tunneling, socat

#### Overview:

I have a software program which communities on UDP port `1046` and I am hoping to hook two computers together.

- Laptop (Required to ALWAYS have VPN connection)
- Desktop (Public ip address)

#### Where I am:

I've seen various bridging tutorials but they seen to involve one computer serving as a proxy and not a direct bridge between the two systems.  I have successfully managed to create a TCP bridge and I'm assuming its not too much harder to force the UDP traffic across that bridge

#### TCP Tunnel

On the "laptop" I run

```
ssh -N -L *:24804:localhost:24804 -R:24804:desktop:24804 user@desktop
```

which I believe creates a 2-way tunnel on the machines between TCP port 24804

I tried `socat udp-listen:1046,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:24804` but when I launched my software it gave me an error that port 1046 was already in use

Is there a simple next step I'm completely missing here?

Thanks!